# Finding all references to a method called by using reflection in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have a class that implements ISupportIncrementalLoading interface. In this interface I am using reflection in order to get data from the data source. As I am passing method names as a string when I use "Find All References" in Visual Studio, it cannot find these classes.

This may cause problems if I change the signature of my method as I will not get any compile time errors, instead I will get a runtime error.

Is there a way to pass the name of the method that will let visual studio to accept it as a reference to the method.

This is my IncrementalCollection Class.

```
public class IncrementalCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private bool hasMoreItems;
    private int currentPage;

    private string datasourceClass;
    private string datasourceMethod;
    private List<Object> parameters;

    public IncrementalCollection(string datasourceClass, string datasourceMethod, List<Object> parameters)
    {
        this.datasourceClass = datasourceClass;
        this.datasourceMethod = datasourceMethod;
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.hasMoreItems = true;
    }

    public void ResetCollection(List<Object> parameters)
    {
        this.parameters = parameters;
        currentPage = 0;
        this.Clear();
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get { return hasMoreItems; }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(
            async () =>
            {
                uint resultCount = 0;

                List<Object> modifiedParameters = new List<object>(this.parameters);
                modifiedParameters.Add(++this.currentPage);

                Type type = Type.GetType(this.datasourceClass);
                MethodInfo method = type.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod(this.datasourceMethod);
                IList<T> result = await (Task<IList<T>>)method.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type, null), modifiedParameters.ToArray());

                if (result == null || result.Count == 0)
                {
                    hasMoreItems = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultCount = (uint)result.Count;

                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            foreach (T item in result)
                                this.Add(item);
                        });
                }

                return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = resultCount };

            }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```

This is how I initialise IncrementalCollection, here I want to pass the name of the method by referencing it somehow.

```
List<Object> parameters = new List<Object>();
parameters.Add(url);
parameters.Add(null);
parameters.Add(null);

IncrementalCollection<User> _users = new IncrementalCollection<User>(_dataService.GetType().FullName, "GetUserList", parameters);
```

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the basic `Func`-style delegates. In your case, the consumer is passing in a delegate that takes one additional parameter:

```
var _users = new IncrementalCollection<User>(page => new DataService().GetUserList(uri, null, null, page));
```

And your `IncrementalCollection` is modified to use `Func`:

```
public class IncrementalCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
  private bool hasMoreItems;
  private int currentPage;
  private Func<int, Task<IList<T>>> func;

  public IncrementalCollection(Func<int, Task<IList<T>>> func)
  {
    this.func = func;
    this.hasMoreItems = true;
  }

  public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
  {
    var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

    return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(async () =>
    {
      uint resultCount = 0;

      var result = await func(++this.currentPage);
      if (result == null || result.Count == 0)
      {
        hasMoreItems = false;
      }
      else
      {
        resultCount = (uint)result.Count;
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(
             CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
             () =>
             {
               foreach (T item in result)
                 this.Add(item);
             });
      }

      return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = resultCount };

    }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
  }
}
```

However, I can't just let that dispatcher code go, and I doubt the `Task.Run` is necessary, since this appears to be I/O-based. It's better to write it more naturally with `async`/`await`:

```
public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
{
  return DoLoadMoreItemsAsync(count).AsAsyncOperation();
}

private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> DoLoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
{
  var result = await func(++this.currentPage);
  if (result == null || result.Count == 0)
  {
    hasMoreItems = false;
  }
  else
  {
    foreach (T item in result)
      this.Add(item);
  }

  return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = result == null ? 0 : result.Count };
}
```

Comment: This was more than I asked for :) I also changed my IncrementalCollection according to your suggestion. Thank you very much for your answer.